# Markdown to Context Workflow

Tags: context, markdown, workflow

I am experimenting with Context and want to be able to write in Markdown but compile with Context. I found this [tutorial](https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/markdowntopdf/) which describes such a workflow but I get the following error when I run `context --environment=ENVMD --mode=standalone test.md`:

```
tex error       > tex error on line 3 in file /Users/xxx/Desktop/context/test.md: ! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in vertical mode
```

My test.md file contains:

```
# This is a heading

## This is a sub heading

- list 1
- list 2
- list 3

## This is another sub-heading
```

My ENVMD.tex file contains:

```
% file ENVMD.tex
\startenvironment ENVMD

   % Setups for fonts, layout, and styles

   \usemodule[filter]

   \defineexternalfilter
     [markdown]
     [filtercommand={pandoc -f \externalfilterparameter{format} -t context 
                     -i \externalfilterinputfile\space
                     -o \externalfilteroutputfile},
      format=markdown,
      directory=output]

\stopenvironment

\doifnotmode{standalone}{\endinput}
\starttext
\processmarkdownfile{\inputfilename}
\stoptext
```

Does anyone know why this doesn't work or know of a better workflow?

### Update 1:

After removing \startenvironment and \stopenvironment as suggested by @Aditya, the output looks like this:

```
1
markdown[title=This is a heading]
1.1
markdown[title=This is a sub heading]
```

### Update 2:

The contents of the test.tex file are:

```
\section[this-is-a-heading]{This is a heading}

\subsection[this-is-a-sub-heading]{This is a sub heading}

\startitemize[packed]
\item
  list 1
\item
  list 2
\item
  list 3
\stopitemize

\subsection[this-is-another-sub-heading]{This is another sub-heading}
```

Comment: Remove the `environment` commands from your document because everything after `\stopenvironment` is ignored and one uses them only when you put your setups in a separate file.

Comment: My understanding is that by invoking `context` with `--mode=standalone` it does not stop processing at the `\stopenvironment` line.

Comment: Simply run `context --extra=markdown test.md`.

Comment: `context --extra=markdown test.md` creates the same error!

Comment: @pdoak Then your installation is faulty.  Please check that TeXlive or ConTeXt Standalone (whichever you are using) is installed properly.

Comment: I installed from MacTex. `context --version` shows 0.63 2016.05.17 19:20. Is there anything else that I can check?

Comment: I wrote the blog post that you linked to. When I wrote the post, `\stopenvironment` did not cause the rest of the file to be ignored; now it does. Therefore, you need to remove the `\startenvironment` and `\stopenvironment` lines; if you do that, then the file should run.

Comment: @Aditya:Thank you. That allows it to run but the output is not what I was expecting. See edited answer above.

Comment: The filter module creates a temp file with an extension '.tex'. Can you also post the content of this file?

Comment: @Aditya:the only files created in the directory are `test.log, test.pdf, test.tuc`

Comment: The command `directory=output` writes everything to a subdirectory `output`. You need to either remove that line or manually create the `output` subdirectory.

Comment: @Aditya: I have just tried using this again after a couple of weeks and it is not working. I get a fatal error in the logs `t-filter        > Fatal Error: Cannot write to file 'output /test2.md.tex'


tex error       > tex error on line 18 in file ENVMD.tex: ! ` Line 18 is `\processmarkdownfile{\inputfilename}`. Any ideas as to what could have changed?

Comment: @pdoak: There is a space after `output`, most likely because you moved the `]` on to next line. The simplest fix is to use `directory=output,` (note the trailing comma)

Comment: @Aditya: That worked. Thank you. I have come across another problem. If there is a space in the file name ie. test 2.md, the output file is not written. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @pdoak: Untested.... You can try adding quotes around `\externalfilterinputfile` and `\externalfilteroutputfile`, but handling of quotes depends on the shell and is not always reliable.

Comment: @Aditya: Putting quotes worked using zsh as the shell. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The `\processmarkdownfile` command is defined in the `markdown` module which has to be loaded with `\usemodule[markdown]`.

```
\startbuffer[markdown]

# This is a heading

## This is a sub heading

- list 1
- list 2
- list 3

## This is another sub-heading

1. list 1
2. list 2
3. list 3

\stopbuffer

\savebuffer[list=markdown,prefix=no,file=test.md]

\usemodule[markdown]

\starttext
\processmarkdownfile{test.md}
\stoptext
```

[image: Output of a markdown document with ConTeXt]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I put `\usemodule[markdown]` into my `env.tex` file right after the `\stopenvirinment` line but I still get the same error.

Comment: Note that this uses the parser for markdown that ships with ConTeXt. That is not as feature rich as the pandoc parser. Of course, the advantage of using the parser that ships with ConTeXt is that it is much quicker than calling an external program. In my blog post, I suggested to use pandoc because I was using some features that are provided by pandoc but not by context.